# Python pickle question. I don't know why this error occurred

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle, shared-memory

Before I ask you, please understand that I am not good at English. im sorry.

```
import...

sharedMem_chk=mp.Value(ctypes.c_bool,False)

def all_loopStop(chk):
    #print("[def]all_loopStop:::ready")
    while True:
        if chk.value==False:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                print("::stop loop::")
                chk.value=True

def __init__():
    test1 = mp.Process(target=all_loopStop, args=(sharedMem_chk,))
    test1.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __init__()
```

This is part of my code.

It works fine when compiling and debugging, but when I write an exe file with cx_freeze and run the exe file I get the following error message:

> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup all_loopStop on **main** failed

After searching for an hour, I think the reason for the error is data not serialized, but the `all_loopStop` function has not needed serialized data, so I don't know why the error occurs.

The development environment is python3.7 32bit, and I'll also attach a detailed debug console window.

I need your help very much. I apologize once again for asking questions with my poor English.
[Debug console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nHvR.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please insert the error as text here instead of picture.

Comment: Maybe try defining all_loopStop in the file where the error occurred. I'm not entirely sure.